# Join pandas dataframes using regex on a column using Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframe df1 and df2. I would like to join the two dataframes using regex on column 'CODE'.

```
df1

STR                                 CODE
Nonrheumatic aortic valve disorders I35
Glaucoma suspect                    H40.0

df2

STR                                 CODE
Nonrheumatic aortic valve disorders I35
Nonrheumatic 1                      I35.1
Nonrheumatic 2                      I35.2
Nonrheumatic 3                      I35.3
Glaucoma suspect                    H40.0
Glaucoma 2                          H40.1
Diabetes                            H50
Diabetes 1                          H50.1                         
Diabetes 1                          H50.2
```

The final output should be like this:

```
STR                                 CODE
Nonrheumatic aortic valve disorders I35
Nonrheumatic 1                      I35.1
Nonrheumatic 2                      I35.2
Nonrheumatic 3                      I35.3
Glaucoma suspect                    H40.0
Glaucoma 2                          H40.1
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "align" the *codes* of 2 dataframes with matching their essential prefixes (obtained by regex substitution) in [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where) condition:

```
df1_codes = df1.CODE.str.replace(r'\..+', '', regex=True)
df2.loc[df2.CODE.str.replace(r'\..+', '', regex=True)\
    .pipe(lambda s: s.where(s.isin(df1_codes))).dropna().index]
```

---

```
                                  STR   CODE
0  Nonrheumatic aortic valve disorders    I35
1                       Nonrheumatic 1  I35.1
2                       Nonrheumatic 2  I35.2
3                       Nonrheumatic 3  I35.3
4                     Glaucoma suspect  H40.0
5                           Glaucoma 2  H40.1
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
(df1.assign(
    CODEA=df1['CODE'].str.split('\.', expand=True)[0])
 .merge(df2.assign(
     CODEA=df2['CODE'].str.split('\.', expand=True)[0]), 
        on='CODEA', suffixes=['_x', '']).loc[:, df1.columns])
```

Output:

```
                                   STR   CODE
0  Nonrheumatic aortic valve disorders    I35
1                       Nonrheumatic 1  I35.1
2                       Nonrheumatic 2  I35.2
3                       Nonrheumatic 3  I35.3
4                     Glaucoma suspect  H40.0
5                           Glaucoma 2  H40.1
```

Comment: Use `str.extract` rather that `split`+slicing, it's much more efficient ;)

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, for having commented my solution! I have just tested with `str.extract` (`(df1.assign(
    CODEA=df1['CODE'].str.extract('(\w\d+)'))
 .merge(df2.assign(
        CODEA=df2['CODE'].str.extract('(\w\d+)')),
        on='CODEA', suffixes=['_x', ''])).loc[:, df1.columns]
`) and timed both approaches: the times of execution were quite similar.

Comment: And with `expand=False`? Have you tested on a large dataset? Maybe the `merge` is a bottleneck and the `extract`/`split` difference is masked by it.

Comment: @mozway: By using `df2 = pd.concat([df2] * 1000000)`, the time of `str.split` approach was: `10.1 s ± 40 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`; the time of the `str.extract`approach was: `10.6 s ± 178 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. In sum, both approaches appear to be equally efficient.